# RTSP Client implementation on Android

Tags: android, streaming, rtsp, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I have seen many questions related to this. Nevertheless there is not an answer for mine I think.

I would like to use an already coded RTSP Client on Android to use with MediaCodec in order to capture a RTSP stream in H264 to then decode and display it. I have used VideoView and MediaPlayer which are well-known to support RTSP streaming in the .setDataSource method (file or rtsp/http path) (unlike MediaExtractor which only supports file or http), but the latency is to high for my purposes.

I would like to use MediaExtractor, but because of that limitation on the setDataSource method it seems to be not an option. Given this, I am searching for some help or examples (tutorial?) that I could use as RTSP Client on Android, or if someone has used MediaExtractor in some way to capture the RTSP stream its help is more than welcome as well.

Thank you so much guys!

rojiark

Comment: Any reason you un-accepted the answer?

Comment: I don't see any performance gains to be had by switching to MediaCodec. Both options use the same native code to play the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

You should know though that is LGPL, which means the rest of your project will become LGPL and if you distribute the application you must also distribute the source code if requested.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need some help. If it works a vote would be nice.

Comment: Btw, if it remains as a jar and you don't change anything it might not affect your project. The law is still pretty new though in this area, as far as I know.

Comment: This is an inverse answer to the question, OP is asking about a client not a server. A useful link non the less though.

Comment: This is no LGPL, this is GPLv3.