# How to make RTSP Client on Android without any third party library?

Tags: android, rtsp, rtsp-client

Just looked on stackoverflow question post link
[RTSP Client Implementation on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492229/rtsp-client-implementation-on-android)

Found another 
[Android RTSP Client](https://weeklybuild.com/2013/03/30/android-rtsp-client/)

Tried to implement with videoview and surfaceview.

```
--http web link video is coming. 
--http using VLC player no video
--rtsp using VLC player no video.
```

I am using code from Android RTSP Client

```
package com.weeklybuild.rtspviewer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  String uri = "rtsp://localhost:8554/test";  //giving Url as per VLC 
  VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById( R.id.videoView );
  v.setVideoURI( Uri.parse(uri) );
  v.setMediaController( new MediaController( this ) );
  v.requestFocus();
  v.start();
 }
}
```

Can Someone tell me why unable to view video using RTSP ?

Comment: have you given internet permission to the app?

Comment: Yes, I have given internet permission also.

Comment: I have installed app IP Webcam from google play and broadcasting video on local http ip address. When i am using that http link in above code. Then i am getting Couldn't open http://192.168.43.87:8080/video: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.43.87:8080/video. While this link is working on phone chrome. Can someone tell me, why this is not working on above code.

Comment: Can you switch your URI to this: rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov and check?

Comment: Yes, above link is working fine. Then why link created by VLC player is not working. Is there any difference in codec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason is that the URI specified is not correct. Since the link,

`rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov`

works, we can be sure that the code works fine. I'm guessing the problem is because there is no codec to the URI provided in the question.

The second link you provided, [Android RTSP Client](https://weeklybuild.com/2013/03/30/android-rtsp-client/) also states that there can be a lot of problems with the codec. (Section 4 in the link)

I'd suggest to add and .stream and check. If that doesn't work then try a different codec.